# android custom listview sorting

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom list and iam trying to sorting the list view by alphabetically but  get wrong every time.

i tried by compare but its didn't work with me.

```
    Context mContext;

    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Movie> movieItems;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
        mContext = activity;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.movieItems = movieItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return movieItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return movieItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
        if (imageLoader == null)imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView rating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
        TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
        TextView year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);
        // getting movie data for the row
        final Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

        // thumbnail image
        thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);


        // title
        title.setText(m.getTitle());
        title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0b6887"));
        // rating
        rating.setText("Rating: " + String.valueOf(m.getRating()));
        rating.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#66890e"));

        // genre
        String genreStr = "";
        for (String str : m.getGenre()) {
            genreStr += str + ", ";
        }
        genreStr = genreStr.length() > 0 ? genreStr.substring(0,
                genreStr.length() - 2) : genreStr;
        genre.setText(genreStr);



        // release year
        year.setText(String.valueOf(m.getYear()));
        year.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2c85cb"));

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Show.class);
                intent.putExtra("rank",m.getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("img",m.getThumbnailUrl());
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("eps", m.getep());
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("typ", m.getGenre());            
                mContext.startActivity(new Intent(intent));
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Thanks All...........................................

Comment: Where is the compare function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this you can sort you listView after you call `new CustomListAdapter` in your **activity** class

```
Collections.sort(movieItems, new Comparator<User>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Movie m1, Movie m2) {
                 return (int) m1.getTitle().charAt(0) - (int) m2.getTitle().charAt(0);
            }
        });
```

Comment: movieList.clear();
        
              listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
              adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
              Collections.sort(movieList, new Comparator<Movie>() {
                  @Override
                  public int compare(Movie m1, Movie m2) {
                       return (int) m1.getTitle().charAt(0) - (int) m2.getTitle().charAt(0);
                  }
              });
              
              listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: you should call *listView.setAdapter(adapter);* before  *Collections.sort* and then call *Collections.sort* with *adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();*

Comment: You are calling *movieList.clear();*, that will clear all movies from movieList ... remove it :)

Comment: worked but there is one problem. when start loading wont sort but when i refresh it sorting and if i remove  movieList.clear() it will add more items to listview and the the saved items will be sort only.

Comment: worked thanks problem was i should add it after 
movieList.add(movie);

Answer (score 0):

Your Movie class must implement Comparable. You should get smth like this

In Movie Class:

```
class Movie implements Comparable<Movie> {
    private String title; //that's yours title

    // Some other code 

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Movie another) {
        return this.title.compareTo(another.title);
    }
}
```

And in CustomListAdapter:

```
public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
    Collections.sort(movieItems);
    this.movieItems = movieItems;
}
```

Comment: please post your Movie class listing including comparable implementation

Comment: omg, man. My field `name` was just for primer. Use your corresponding field `title`. I changed an example so it would be obvious for you. Don't follow exactly what people say to you. Try to understand how it works and change it in appropriate way :)

Comment: i added this but still not working look after change : http://textuploader.com/k3hx http://textuploader.com/k3hg